# How do I auto increment an xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to auto increment my xml file. I have a form that people submit and save information into a xml doc. I can't get to auto increment. The data is save but the id stay the same which is 0

XML document schema

```
<affiliates>

    <affiliate id="0">
        <FullName></FullName>
        <Company></Company>
        <Degree_Certificate></Degree_Certificate>
        <City></City>
        <StateProvidenceRegion></StateProvidenceRegion>
        <Phone></Phone>
        <Emailaddress></Emailaddress>
        <Descriptions></Descriptions>
    </affiliate>

<affiliates>
```

PHP code: problems:

```
$root = $doc->createElement('affiliate', '');
$aff = count($root);
for ($i = 0; $i < $aff; $i++)
{
    $root->setAttribute('id', $i);
    $fullname = $doc->createElement('FullName', $fname.' '.$lname);
    $certdegree = $doc->createElement('Degree_Certificate', $degree);
    $Company = $doc->createElement('Company', $company);
    $Street = $doc->createElement('City', $address);
    $StateProvidenceRegion = $doc->createElement('StateProvidenceRegion', $state);
    $Phone = $doc->createElement('Phone', $phone);
    $EmailAddress = $doc->createElement('Emailaddress', $email);
    $Description = $doc->createElement('Descriptions', $message);
    $doc->appendChild($root);
    $root->appendChild($fullname);
    $root->appendChild($Company);
    $root->appendChild($certdegree);
    $root->appendChild($Street);
    $root->appendChild($StateProvidenceRegion);
    $root->appendChild($Phone);
    $root->appendChild($EmailAddress);
    $root->appendChild($Description);
    $doc->documentElement->appendChild($root);
}
```

Help me please with this code. PHP is not my strong point. What piece of code did I not add.

Comment: Not familiar with XML in PHP, but I think `$fullname = $doc->createElement()` should be `$fullname = $root->createElement()`. And the same for the other elements under the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//Process form data here.

//Get the XML Document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("affiliates.xml"); //Load the existing XML here.

//Get the affiliates node here
$root = $doc->documentElement;

//Get the ID of this record here.
//If you know that no affiliate entries will ever be deleted, then you can use the total number of entries as the next increment value.
$totalAffiliates = $root->childNodes->length;

$node = $doc->createElement("affiliate");
$node->setAttribute("id", $totalAffiliates);
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("FullName", $fname . ' ' . $lname));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("Degree_Certificate", $degree));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("Company", $company));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("City", $address));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("StateProvidenceRegion", $state));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("Phone", $phone));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("Emailaddress", $email));
$node->appendChild($doc->createElement("Descriptions", $message));

$root->appendChild($node);

//Write your XML back to the file.
?>
```

This code should give you what you need. You will need to adjust it in a few places, to fit what you already have.

Comment: I need to know more about the original code. For example, the root of the XML schema should be "affiliates", not "affiliate".

Where is the above PHP code called from? Your code is missing essential information to correcting your problem.

Comment: The form is setup to email data and save data in a xml file. so $fname and $lname are capture information from the form. Again I have to iterate I am new to php. If company I work for was using asp.net hosting everything would be ok.  I can post the form and all the php code if you would like.

Comment: Is the XML document pre-existing, or is it always a newly created document?

Comment: The XML document is pre-existing